# Mono.Cairo and native UI

Tags: c#, winforms, vector, mono, cairo

I want to build an application for Windows, Mac and Linux - based on mono.

One part of the application will need a vector drawing library.

I found Mono.Cairo which looks good, but every howto I can find so far is based on GTK#.
As my goal is to build native UIs, I'll need Mono.Cairo on a Winforms-Control and also accessible from a NSView for Mac.

Is this even possible? Or is there another solution?

Thanks!